# expected a qualified name after 'typename'

Tags: c++

```
template<typename Type> class SingleList;

template<typename Type> class ListNode{
private:
    friend typename SingleList<Type>;  
    //this line appears"expected a qualified name after 'typename'"

    ListNode():nextNode(NULL){}

    ListNode(const Type item,ListNode<Type> *next=NULL):nodeData(item),nextNode(next){}

    ~ListNode(){
        nextNode=NULL;
}

public:
        Type GetData();
        friend ostream& operator<< <Type>(ostream& ,ListNode<Type>&);

private:
        Type nodeData;
        ListNode *nextNode;
};
```

The code:

```
friend typename SingleList<Type>;
```

expected a qualified name after 'typename' and how to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want

```
friend class SingleList<Type>;
```

`typename` can be used instead of `class` inside the template parameter declaration, but not everywhere.

Comment: `clang` just gave me OP's error, while both `MingW` and `MSVC` compile same source-code without issue.

Comment: Maybe there is a `clang` flag that needs to be added or removed, to make `clang` compatible with other compilers?