# Should typename be before or after const in C++?

Tags: c++, class, oop, constants, typename

Should I write:

```
template<class T> class Foo {
    typename const T* x;
};
```

or:

```
template<class T> class Foo {
    const typename T* x;
};
```

Comment: is `typename` even allowed in this case? I thought it was used only to disambiguate the syntax for static data members and member types.

Comment: If any of them causes a compilation error, that's the one you shouldn't use.

Comment: Simply:`template<class T> class Foo {
    const T* x = nullptr;
};`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`typename` is not used like this, so both cases are invalid and should produce a compilation error, like this:

```
main.cpp:4:20: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
    const typename T* x;
                   ^
```

Here you would need something like `T::myType` to go on.

Or even this, which is worse:

```
main.cpp:4:14: error: expected a qualified name after 'typename'
    typename const T* x;
             ^
main.cpp:4:14: error: expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers
```

Relevant example in [expected a qualified name after 'typename'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998121/expected-a-qualified-name-after-typename).

---

> The keyword typename was introduced to specify that the identifier that follows is a type

Read more in: [Officially, what is typename for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for)

Answer (score 7):

`typename` needs to go with the type your are trying to get.  For example if you have

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t)
{
    typename const T::iterator bar = t.begin();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> bar{1,2,3}
    foo(bar);
}
```

You will get a compiler error for `typename const  T::const_iterator bar = t.begin();` along the lines of

> expected nested-name-specifier before 'const'

Where as

```
const typename T::iterator bar = t.begin();
```

Works just fine.

---

For a comprehensive explanation on when, where, and why `template` and `typename` need to appear see: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Answer (score 2):

There's no point in using `typename` here.

You'll have to use if you want to access an alias type like `T::type` where you can't have `const` between `typename` and `T::type`

```
const typename T::type * x;  // ok
typename T::type const * x;  // ok
typename const T::type * x;  // error
```